# How to set image for a specific tagged UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating many UIImageViews with a unique tag

```
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.frame = CGRect(x:  tableView.bounds.size.width-100, y: 20, width: 40, height: 40)
    imgView.image = UIImage(named: "arrowUp")
    imgView.tag = section
    viewHeader.addSubview(imgView)
```

Now I want to set an other image "arrowDown" for a specific tagged UIImageView how can I programmatically set it?

Something like:

***imgView.tag[i].image = UIImage(named: "arrowDown")***

Comment: Note that using tags is a rather fragile way to keep track of your views. As Sh_Khan indicated in their answer, it would be better to keep your image views in an array or some other structure that holds references to your image view(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(viewHeader.viewWithTag(<#YourTag#>) as? UIImageView)?.image = UIImage(named: "arrowDown")
```

---

Or create an array

```
var all = [UIImageView]()

viewHeader.addSubview(imgView)
all.append(imgView)
```

Then

```
all[tag].image = /////
```